Formula to return row pairs of data based on number in second row
In Excel, I have two rows of data.
In each column,

Row 1 contains a letter of the alphabet.
Row 2 contains a number associated with the letter above it.

How do I return the values from only those columns where the number is less than 15 and greater than 0, and ignore the rest?
Sample Data
Desired results in A4:C6




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K




1
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K


2
30
0
0
14
0
0
9
0
0
17
0


3













4
D
G
M










6
14
9
6













If you want the range to include future values you can use the entire row:
=FILTER(1:2,(2:2>0)*(2:2<15))

If you want to skip a row you could use a few approaches such as CHOOSEROWS:
=FILTER(CHOOSEROWS(1:3, 1, 3), (3:3>0)*(3:3<15))

=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(1:3, (3:3>0)*(3:3<15)), 1, 3)


Should be easy using the FILTER() function:


=FILTER(A1:M2,(A2:M2>0)*(A2:M2<=15))


Here is the update:


=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(A1:M3,(A3:M3>0)*(A3:M3<=15),""),1,3)


